# Fatal error for permissions in Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I got following `error`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/.../third_party/base_facebook.php on line 1106
```

my function is,

```
public function isPhotoPermission()
        {
            $facebook = new Facebook();
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions","GET",array('access_token' => $access_token));
            if( array_key_exists('user_photos', $permissions['data'][0]) ) 
            {
                return 1;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

that `1106` line is,

```
1105:  protected function throwAPIException($result) {
1106:    $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
1107:    switch ($e->getType()) { ....
```

error occurring by following code:

```
$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions","GET",array('access_token' => $access_token));
```

Where is the Problem? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't forget the parameters as for the `Facebook()` constructor?

```
$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Or perhaps did you initialize your `$facebook` object somewhere else in the code? In that case, you should:

- either pass `$facebook` to your `isPhotoPermission()` function in order to get it back,
- or set `$facebook` as `global` whether it is initialized in another function,
- or simply remove the `$facebook = new Facebook();` line if `$facebook` has been defined outside a function (would mean it is already `global`).